# ampersand symbol in url param, after encoding also throwing an error - MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, urlencode

In one of my action methods , I do have a parameter "filename", which some times can be a string with ampersand symbol.
The problem is when ever we have an ampersand symbol its not hitting the method.

I have encoded the url but still its not hitting.

```
var renderDetailLink = function (data, type, row, meta) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("DocDetails", "Docs", new { docKey = "__docKey__", isReleased = "__isReleased__", isFilterDocs = "__isFilterDocs__", fileName = "__fileName__" })';
            url = url.replace('__docKey__', row.X);
            url = url.replace('__isReleased__', row.Y);
            url = url.replace('__isFilterDocs__', row.Z);
            url = url.replace('__fileName__', encodeURIComponent(row.FileName) + "/");
            var link = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + data + "</a>";
            return link;
        }
```

The above is the javascript method which i am using to encode the url part.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("DocDetails/{docKey}/{isReleased}/{isFilterDocs}/{*fileName}")]
        public ActionResult DocDetails(long docKey, string isReleased, bool isFilterDocs, string fileName)
        {
          ///

            return View();
        }
```

My controller action looks like above.

In few places I have read, by encoding the url we can pass &, but in few other places I saw since .net engine restricts & we cannot simply pass it by encoding it.

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

- Similar kind of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180785/2377818) fixed here.
- Some of the useful links here for [URL Encoding](https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/using-url-encoding-to-handle-special-characters-in-a-document-uri).
- Accessing URL Parts from a [Rewrite Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Preserving_Original_URL).

Comment: Hey @Arunprasanth, is your issue fixed?

Comment: No , I dont see any information in your ans , its all just regular url related to encoding.